# Is it possible to change element's Knockout binding/clean up previous event handlers based on value of KO observable

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have 2 KO custom bindings: the first creates a jQuery sliding panel widget, and the second creates a jQuery accordion widget. The content "hidden" by either widget is the same; the idea is that, on a mobile device, the content is displayed to the user by invoking the sliding panel, and on a desktop, the content is displayed to the user by expanding the accordion.

I want to create a single KO binding that will determine which binding to apply to the element, based on a KO observable I've created that detects whether the user is on a mobile device or not.

I've come up with this binding to determine whether to apply a panel binding or an accordion binding based on the user's device:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.panelAccordion = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};
        var isMobile = options.mobile ? typeof options.mobile === 'boolean' ? options.mobile : false : false;

        if (isMobile !== null && typeof isMobile !== 'undefined') {
            if (isMobile) {
                ko.bindingHandlers.panel.update(element, valueAccessor);
            } else {
                ko.bindingHandlers.multiAccordion.update(element, valueAccessor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This appears to work just fine if the screen size is static, but I'd like to gracefully handle the switch between the two (portrait to landscape, or resizing a browser window for example).  It appears to be applying the correct binding when the screen resize occurs, but both the "panel" and "accordion" bindings have click handlers within them that need to be cleared so as not to interfere when the "new" binding is applied.  In other words, the click handler to invoke the sliding panel needs to be removed so that the click handler to invoke the accordion (which will be applied to the same element) can be correctly invoked, and vice-versa.

Right now it appears to be executing both click handlers.

I've tried jQuery's .off() and .unbind() methods with no success, so either I'm not putting those calls in the correct place, or I need to handle this another way.

Comment: Instead of wrapping two separate bindings in one, you could use two separate templates and switch between them, depending if `isMobile` or not.

Comment: That was my initial approach but I don't like maintaining 2 sets of mark-up.  Since the only mark-up difference between the two is the <div> element to which I am applying the binding, either "panel" or "multiAccordion," I want an elegant way to dynamically determine which binding is applied.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to dynamically modify bindings at runtime. While you can modify bindings with either `ko.bindinghandlers.<name>.preprocess` or `ko.bindingProvider.instance.preprocessNode`, both happen before the binding context is applied, so you would not have access to `isMobile` at the time they run.

I would like to suggest using a component as a workaround (requires Knockout 3.3). You could create one looking like this:

```
<panel-accordion params="mobile: isMobile">
  <h1>This content is shared between both widgets</h1>
</panel-accordion>
```

that toggles between both bindings as required.

```
ko.components.register('panel-accordion', {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        this.mobile = params.mobile;
    },
    template:
        '<!-- ko if: mobile -->' +
          '<div data-bind="panel: true">' +
            '<!-- ko template: { nodes: $componentTemplateNodes } --><!-- /ko -->' +
          '</div>' +
        '<!-- /ko -->' +
        '<!-- ko ifnot: mobile -->' +
          '<div data-bind="accordion: true">' +
            '<!-- ko template: { nodes: $componentTemplateNodes } --><!-- /ko -->' +
          '</div>' +
        '<!-- /ko -->' +
});
```

This way, the elements to which the `panel` and `accordion` bindings are bound are properly destroyed whenever `isMobile` changes, taking care of the cleaning up.

Comment: That sounds like it could work; I'll have to take a look. Thank you!

Comment: @JasonMansfield that example was written off the cuff; please let me know how it goes and if you run into any trouble.